# ASP.NET - Owin Steam Provider not authenticating

Tags: c#, asp.net, vba, security, owin

I've added the Owin Security Providers Steam, and it works like a charm, logges in and shows logged in content when I debug it on my computer (localhost). But when I upload it to GoDaddy Windows Host, after I log in, it redirects me to the login page again, and doesn't get authenticated?

Anyone experienced this before?

You can check it out here: [csgoteamstatistics.com](http://www.csgoteamstatistics.com/)

Comment: what is your version that owin package ?

Comment: Fixed it, forgot to add the owin package reference to the web.config =)